# Convert List to grouped list in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, list, spring-boot

I want to convert the below list with attributes to group the similar group and concatenate the subgroup values as below expected output using Java Spring Boot. This is my code.

```
    for (JuniorAreaSubgroup value : lstJuniorAreaSubgroup) {
        juniorAreaSubgroupMap.setJuniorArea(value.getJuniorArea());
        lstSubgroup.add(lstJuniorAreaSubgroup.stream().filter(value.getJuniorArea()) -> 
                String.join(",", value.getSubgroup()));
        juniorAreaSubgroupMap.setSubgroup(lstSubgroup);
        lstSubgroup.clear();
    }
```

-

```
[
{
    "group": "Tins",
    "subgroup": "G13AA"
},
{
    "group": "Tins",
    "subgroup": "G13AD"
},
{
    "group": "Cans",
    "subgroup": "G13DA"
},
{
    "group": "Cans",
    "subgroup": "G13DB"
},
{
    "group": "Cans",
    "subgroup": "G13DD"
}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
{
    "group": "Tins",
    "subgroup": [“G13AA”, "G13AD”]
},
{
    "group": "Cans",
    "subgroup": [“G13DA”, "G13DB”, "G13DD”]
} 
]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your attempt as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like JSON. This example will set up the data with proper Java objects instead:

```
public class Grouping {

    public class Person {
        String group;
        String subgroup;

        Person(String group, String subgroup){
            this.group = group;
            this.subgroup=subgroup;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new Person("Tins", "G13AA"));
        list.add(new Person("Tins", "G13AD"));
        list.add(new Person("Cans", "G13DA"));
        list.add(new Person("Cans", "G13DB"));
        list.add(new Person("Cans", "G13DD"));

        Map<String, List<String>> result = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.group, Collectors.mapping(p->p.subgroup, Collectors.toList())));

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

will result in:

```
{Cans=[G13DA, G13DB, G13DD], Tins=[G13AA, G13AD]}
```

Comment: Hi @Mick, I need one more way to replace the value G13DA with G13, G23.

Comment: You would rather do that while you construct the data (?).